# WPF - Add database value to List<class>

Tags: c#, wpf, database, list

I want to have all value in my database inside `List<data> dataList`. I have 3 columns that is idx, tag and value and i want all value in idx,tag and value are in dataList. In Data.cs i have only this :

```
public class data
{
    int idx;
    string tag;
    string value;
}
```

in MainWindow.xaml.cs i tried to add idx row with this :

```
List<data> dataList = new List<data>();
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["idx"].Rows)
{
    dataList.Add(row["idx"].ToString());
}
```

but it's error, ds is my dataset (idx,tag,value). How can i add all my dataset values into the dataList?

edit :  how can i get the specific value of the dataList? if i want to output the value of idx in row 2, how can i get the value of idx[2] in messagebox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
dataList.Add(row["idx"].ToString());
```

Its

```
dataList.Add(new data(){idx=(int)row["idx"], tag=(string)row["tag"], value=(string)row["value"]);
```

---

Update 1
You can access the dataList's row as follows

```
int row = 0;
Data o = dataList[row];
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(o.value);
```

Comment: thank you. but how can i get the value of the dataList? if i want to output the value of idx in row 2, how can i messagebox it?

Comment: i try to use this to get all row `item.idx.ToString()` but what about specific row?

Comment: @Mirza I updated my answer based on your comments. What is item? Is it a Data object?

Answer (score 0):

According to your edit (members have to be public or use a Get()):

try

```
         int val = (datalist.ElementAt(1) as Data).idx;
```